# Can't get Buy X get Y Free for a category

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I am trying to set up a **Buy X Get Y Free** promo.

The idea is that if you **buy 10 items** in a **specific category** and get 1 (the 11th) item free. No matter what I do I am not able to get this done.

**In Conditions I have:**

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

- If total quantity is 10 for a    sub selection of items in cart
  matching ALL of these conditions:    Category is 41

**In Actions I have:**

Buy x get Y Free and I have the following options:

- Discount Amount 1
- Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To 1
- Discount Qty Step (Buy X) 10
- Apply to Shipping Amount NO
- Free Shipping NO
- Stop Further Rules Processing NO

Please let me know What I should do.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess, but if your condition is "total quantity is 10" then the 11th "free" item would fail that condition.  I think it should read "total quantity is greater than or equal 10".

Comment: I have tried "total quantity is greater than or equal 10" and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use below extension for Buy X get Y Free for a category

**BUY X**

- Buy product X get, product Y free, discounted.

**SPEND X**

- Spend amount X, get product Y free, discounted.

**COUPON X**

- Use coupon X get product Y free, discounted.

**CATEGORY X**

- Buy products that belong to a specific category X, get product Y
  free, discounted.

Extension Link = https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-buy-x-get-y-free